# evaluation order and printing in printf

Tags: c, printf

I've seen questions about i++ ++i etc. but I have a small, somewhat different question. 
suppose I have some thing like this:

```
 printf("%d %d", P, P);
```

and P is a function

```
 int P(){
      printf("HEY");
      return 0;
 }
```

what will be printed
HEYHEY00 or HEY0HEY0 ?

Comment: I don't exactly have access to a program to try it with at the moment. so I was hoping for a quick answer since google didn't help me

Comment: That's all good and well, but this is not a suitable question for Stackoverflow. There are numerous online compilers/IDEs that you can use. Try http://compileonline.com/.

Comment: I assume you mean `printf("%d %d", p(), p());`

Answer (score 3):

Just run it.

This program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int P(){
  printf("HEY");
  return 0;
}
int main() {
  printf("%d %d", P(), P());
  return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
HEYHEY0 0
```

Why? The arguments are evaluated (P is called) before the code for printf is actually entered.

EDIT: According to @Shafik bellow, the C standard does *not* guarantee the order of the evaluation of arguments, so if there had been two functions with different strings, the order of those strings wouldn't be predictable.

Comment: In this case it may not matter but the order of evaluation of function arguments in unspecified. So if there had been calls to two different functions the output could vary. So it is deceptive to say that just running the program will tell you what it does.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Yes, but no matter what the arguments (in whatever order), are evaluated before the function is called. Right?

Comment: Yes, they are both evaluated before but if the OP used `P1()` and `P2()` which had different output the result would no longer be predictable. Especially since the OP mentioned `i++ ++i` order of evaluation is important.

Answer (score 2):

The evaluation of the arguments in **printf()** as per standards is undefined.  but it prints only after total evaluation of arguments.
so in above example both p()'s are evaluated first, when they evaluated they print "HEY" 2 times  first then their returned values (0 and 0) are printed so output became **"HEYHEY00"**.

Comment: The order in which function arguments are evaluated is *unspecified*.

Comment: But printing is done only after evaluation so first hey's are printed then their returned values are printed . that's y output is HEYHEY00

Comment: i agree with u @dbush but as far as question is concerned , he asked why the output is "heyhey0 0" . as evaluation done before printing out put is "HEYHEY0 0".